# VB6 constants flags in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

So I'm migrating an app I didn't write over to .NET and I'm not sure what the flag control does specifically and I also can't seem to find the equivalent of Flags control, is there even one?

Thanks a lot!

```
Public Sub Flip_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, 
                ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuFile_Import_Flips.Click
    Dim cdlOFNHideReadOnly As Object
    Dim cdlOFNFileMustExist As Object
CommonDialog1.Flags = cdlOFNFileMustExist + cdlOFNHideReadOnly
```

Comment: What does `VB6` have to do with this code?

Comment: NET has specific classes for these _CommonDialogs_. For example you have an [OpenFileDialog class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) and there is no Flag property but individual properties. CheckFileExist, ShowReadOnly

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed s/he is porting VB6 to VB.NET, so some knowledge of VB6 might be helpful

Comment: Stop the habit of declaring things as object though; there are few cases where that is needed; they have an actual type, use that to avoid boxing and possible data conversion errors

Comment: `As Object` would have been an offense even in VB6. These are `Long` integers, declare them as such.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Didn't write the code, but thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flags are equivalent to:

```
    OpenFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = True
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = False
```

But since these are default values you should NOT need to specify them.

Comment: *But since these are default values you should **not** need to specify them*?

Comment: @Mat'sMug You are correct. I've updated my answer. Thanks.